# Will it be better to use past simple or present perfect

Tags: past-tense

> Do you remember my name? I **have bought** some records from you in
>   the past.

Shall I use past simple instead of the present perfect?

I think perfect is better as it has a relevance even now I don't buy from him.

Comment: _I bought some records from you in the past._ but _I have bought some records from you lately._

Comment: "in the past" does not require simple past....

Answer (score 1):

- **I have bought some records from you in the past.** [the act of buying is in the past, we don't know when and may have occurred more than once.]
- **I bought some records from you**. [last week, yesterday, last  year].

There is only one time being referred to. A single act of buying.

Answer (score 0):

Present perfect is used

1. When an action is completed in the very recent past or
2. When the precise time of the action is not important or not known.

Here, it is the 2nd case. The action `you buying the records` is already completed and the time of completion of action is not important. You are bringing it up in the conversation to show a connection to the present. So present perfect would be completely right.

> Hey!! I have bought some records from you.

But when you add `in the past` at the end of the above sentence, you are saying that this has happened in the past and not recently. So you could use lose `in the past` from the above sentence.

Comment: in the past is like recently and lately, and not like: last year etc. It does not refer to a single event and does not require simple past.